# Width change when slide out menu activates

Tags: jquery, css

http://derp.club/scribbles/

I have that site set up above, and my problem is that whenever I click on the slide out menu at the top and then click it to close again, you can see the width of the content changing (the box with the black border). I have pinpointed it to be a width percentage issue, but short of setting the width to be a fixed value, I can't fix the problem. However, I still want the width of the content to be responsive, so I'm hoping someone here can point me to a direction to fix this.

```
.content {
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
top: 5%;
left: 0px;  
}
```

That seems to be the part of the code that is causing the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the width of your `.mm-page` when you add open class to `.mm-menu`

```
.mm-menu {
    width: 30%; <!-- allow it to take 30 % of total 100% document width -->
}

.mm-page {
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 70%; <!-- rest (100 - 30) of width -->
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 30%;  <!-- leave the 30% margin for side nav bar -->
}
h1 {
    line-height: normal !important <!-- rest the line height here -->
}
```

Comment: That works if I want to change the look of the content, but I'm looking to keep the look constant, like the menu is pushing aside the content.

Comment: @user3889997 not understood what exaxtly yo are looking for. Post image of jsfiddle of expected output

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21666216/Untitled-1.jpg

The top is what I would like it to look like. Currently, that's what it does. Except when I click on the menu button again to close the side menu, the width of the black bordered box changes (.content).

If you change .content to a fixed width (e.g. 900px), that's the effect I am trying to achieve, where the box width doesn't jump when I close the side menu. However, I don't want to use a fixed width because I want the content to be responsive.

Comment: Ah, checked again, doesn't work. I still get the same result as the bottom screenshot.

Comment: @user3889997 did you change line-height of your header?

Answer (score -1):

Your **CSS classes-[.contentinside,.contentinsider]** are using padding as 5% which varies on transition, you should use them in px. And, for responsiveness you have to go for media query.